# Windows 8.1 - What is Enable this program to work with SkyDrive files?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

While using the new Windows 8.1, I played around with the compatibility settings for certain .exe files. In the Properties window, go to the Compatibility tab.

There you will see an entry named *Enable this program to work with SkyDrive files*. Any idea what this setting does and how it impacts the functioning of a desktop application, when enabled?

[image: Compatibility setting in Windows 8.1]

Comment: It means you will grant it permissions to your Skydrive folder which is now a system level variable because its part of the User profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft explained this [setting in an article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows):

**Enable this program to work with SkyDrive files:**

> Try this setting if the program can't see or open files on SkyDrive.
>   **Note:** when large files are being downloaded there may be a long delay,
>   with no progress bar reflecting the download.

[By default SkyDrive in 8.1 doesn't download all files](http://blogs.windows.com/skydrive/b/skydrive/archive/2013/09/30/skydrive-introduces-smart-files-in-windows-8-1.aspx) and so older tools my not work correctly.

He is also a [tweet from a Microsoft employee](https://twitter.com/appcompatguy/status/377871135469080576):

> Since SkyDrive defaults to offline, a direct look at the file system
>   won't see files. This is to help that.

Comment: Thanks pointing me in the right direction. I will test things further and try to explain this in some step by step guide, with screenshots and examples.

Comment: have you done the tests? Does it work?

Comment: My learning of this feature is summarized here: http://www.7tutorials.com/fix-programs-dont-work-skydrive-files-windows-81